# How to add a check icon with MUI or Tailwind CSS to all the selected value in the dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I want to add a small check/tick icon beside the value eg: Operations ✓ if user selects operations in the TopicList dropdownlist. The TopicList is a class component to get the data from the database which consist of:
Operations, Array, Repetition, Function, Selection. If user selects 2 different values then eg:
Operations ✓
Array ✓
Repetition
Function
Selection.
How can I modify this code to solve this issue?
Here is an image of how I would like it to be if user selects Array.
[image]

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TopicList from "../Components/topicList";
import CheckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Check';

function CreateEvent(success, message) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState([]); // array to store selected values

  const getDataFromTopicList = (val) => {
    if (val !== "" && !selectedValues.includes(val)) {
      setSelectedValues([...selectedValues, val]);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(selectedValues); // selectedValues array contains all selected values from all TopicList components

    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: BASE_URL + "events/submitEvent",
      data: {
        topicId: selectedValues,
      },

      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          toast.success("Successfully Created", {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          });
        } else {
          toast.error(response.data.message, {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response) {
          toast.error(err.response.data.message, {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          });
        } else {
          toast.error("Failed to Create", {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          });
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          <h1>
            Create an Event
          </h1>
          <div>
            <div>
              <TopicList
                selectedValues={selectedValues}
                getDataFromTopicList={getDataFromTopicList}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateEvent;
```

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import CheckIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Check";

const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;

export default class TopicList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    topics: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(BASE_URL + `events/topic`).then((res) => {
      const topics = res.data;
      this.setState({ topics });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select required onChange={(val) => this.getCat(val.target.value)}>
        {this.state.topics.map((topic) => (
          <option value={topic.topicId}>
          {topic.topic}
          {this.props.selectedValues.includes(topic.topicId) && <CheckIcon style={{ color: "green" }} />}
        </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the posted code has MUI but is not using its components in `TopicList`.

Here is a basic example that makes use of the MUI `Select`, and with implementation of the needed `CheckIcon` on multiple selected values.

Minimized demo of below example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gkfbnn?file=src/App.js)

The example omitted the data fetching part for simplicity, but it keeps the same `topics` state and get props for `selectedValues` in `TopicList`.

The update function for `selectedValues` also changed for MUI component but the state value itself remained to be an array of selected `topicId`, so hopefully it could be wired up for the data fetching without large refectoring of existing code.

Imports for MUI components in `TopicList`:

```
import OutlinedInput from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import CheckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Check';
```

The output of modified `TopicList`:

```
<FormControl sx={{ m: 3, width: 300 }}>
  <InputLabel id="topic-form-input-label">Topic</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="topic-form-label"
    id="multiple-topic-select"
    multiple
    value={this.props.selectedValues}
    onChange={this.props.onChange}
    input={<OutlinedInput label="Topic" />}
    renderValue={(selected) =>
      selected
        .map((topicId) => {
          const selectedTopic = this.state.topics.find(
            (item) => item.topicId === topicId
          );
          return selectedTopic ? selectedTopic.topic : topicId;
        })
        .join(", ")
    }
  >
    {this.state.topics.map((topic) => {
      const selected = this.props.selectedValues.includes(topic.topicId);
      return (
        <MenuItem key={topic.topicId} value={topic.topicId}>
          {selected && (
            <ListItemIcon>
              <CheckIcon style={{ color: "green" }} />
            </ListItemIcon>
          )}
          <ListItemText inset={!selected} primary={topic.topic} />
        </MenuItem>
      );
    })}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Selected values passed from the parent component:

```
const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState([]);
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const {
    target: { value },
  } = event;
  setSelectedValues(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
};
```

```
<TopicList
  selectedValues={selectedValues}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, demo, and edited code. It works how I want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70136389/16048859) you can see an example of a select with checkbox inside it.
to see the code just click the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rahqrq-sd2m2b?file=demo.js).

Comment: Thank you for your reply and link to the demo. It helped me better understand how to apply these components and better understanding the demo.